# Persist errors array after page reload

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am now trying to build a history of all the QR codes a person has generated, save the codes to local storage, then loop through local storage and show these codes on the page.

I would like the date that the codes were created to appear next to the code, as the 'bullet'.

So I am trying to create a multi-dimensional array in Javascript holding an object containing the key value properties, where the key is the date, but when I output this on the page using the variable 'today' as the key holding the date, I get the literal string 'today' as supposed to the 'dd/mm/yyyy' date that I intended to have. @OhGodWhy, perhaps you might be able to help here?

```
index.html//

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>QR Code Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
    href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
    href="css/styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" href="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="input-form">
            <h1>QR Code Generator</h1>
            <div class="row qr_code">
                <span v-show="errors" class="error">
                Please ensure that at least one of the form fields is filled 
    in.
                </span>
            </div>
            <form class="row qr_code">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input v-on:click="generate_url" class="btn btn-success" 
    value="Generate QR Code">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="url-link" name="url-link">URL:</label>
                    <input type="text" v-model="url" id="url-link" 
    class="url-link">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label for="pixel_size" name="pixel_size">Pixels: 
   </label>
                    <input type="text" v-model="pixel_size" id="pixel_size" 
    class="pixel_size">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label for="transparent" name="transparent">Transparent? 
   </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="transparent" 
    id="transparent" class="transparent" true-value="transparent" false- 
   value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <select v-on:change="on_change(this.value)" v- 
   model="image_type" class="dropdown">
                        <option value="png">PNG Image</option>
                        <option value="svg">SVG Image</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="row generated-code">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <p class="generated-code">Generated Code: <span v- 
   show="show_url" class="generated-qr-code">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h2>QR Code History</h2>
                    <ul v-for="(url in url_log">
                        <li>{{ url }}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"> 
   </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

// app.js

```
    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#input-form',
      data: {
    url: "",
    pixel_size: "",
    transparent: "",
    image_type: "",
    show_url: false,
    errors: false,
    url_log: []
      },
       methods: {
    generate_url: function(){
        if (!this.url && !this.pixel_size && !this.transparent && 
    !this.image_type){
          this.errors = true;
      } else {
        this.show_url = true;
        var url = 'https://qrtag.net/api/qr_' + this.transparent + '_' + 
    this.pixel_size + '.' + this.image_type + '?url=' + this.url;
        localStorage.setItem('url', url);
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 
    0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
        if (localStorage.getItem('url')){
          this.url_log.push({today: localStorage.getItem('url')});
        }
        console.log(this.url_log);
      }
    },
    on_change: function(value){
      console.log(value);
    }
      },
      mounted() {
    console.log('App mounted!');

     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple local storage solution to temporarily store them there. Be mindful, though, that you should handle both the creation **and** cleanup of this. Below you can see a simple example:

```
methods: {
  synchronize_errors: (field, name) {
    const errors = localStorage.getItem('errors') || {}

    errors[field] = name

    localStorage.setItem('errors', errors)
  }
}
```

And then you can utilize this within the pointed method:

```
mounted: function () {
  const errors = localStorage.getItem('errors') || {}

  Object.keys(errors).forEach((field) => {
    this.errors.push(errors[error])
  })
}
```

Now cleanup is a bit more difficult, but you could do something as simple as:

```
beforeDestroy: function () {
  localStorage.removeItem('errors')
}
```

Comment: This looks like an intelligent answer - although it would be great if you could perhaps show me how to integrate this code further with the script that I already have. Where would the 'mounted' function go, for example? Thanks, Rob

Comment: Actually @Ohgodwhy I have found the offending article - the input field in my html had a class of 'submit', meaning the data was cleared.

Comment: @RobertYoung The `mounted` and `beforeDestroy` functions are [life cycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks). These are top level properties of the `Vue` or `Component` object (and siblings of method)

Comment: please see another question I have on the same code @Ohgodwhy - pls assist!

Comment: @RobertYoung Please don't modify your question to be something completely different. Revert it back to your original. If my answer was helpful, then select this as the correct answer and click the "Checkmark". Then ask a new question where you're stumped. This isn't the correct format for Stackoverflow.